# GNUplot fit with only x-errors in version 5?

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting, least-squares, chi-squared

I'm trying to fit my data using GNUplot. As it happens my data only has x-error bars. I heard version 5 is supposed to allow fitting using x errors only. How can one do this? I tried the following but as you can see I get errors that I cannot figure out:

```
gnuplot> fit f(x) "data1m" using 2:3:4 with xerrorbars via b,u,n
     warning: 
> Implied independent variable y not found in fit function.
> Assuming version 4 syntax with zerror in column 3 but no zerror keyword.

                                        ^
     Need via and either parameter list or file
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to work with x errors only, but you could use a very small constant y error.
Try `fit f(x) "data1m" using 2:3:4:(1E-38) xyerrors via b,u,n`